# RxJava - How to test a function with inner "toBlocking" call

Tags: java, observable, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm trying to add some unit tests to following piece of code:

```
public List<Stuff> extractStuff(Scheduler scheduler, List<Token> tokens) {
    List<Observable<List<Stuff>>> observables = tokens
            .stream()
            .map(token-> Observable.just(getStuffByToken(token)).subscribeOn(scheduler))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Stuff> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Stuff> stuff: Observable.merge(observables).toBlocking().toIterable()) {
        result.addAll(stuff);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I want `Stuff` objects to be fetched with parallelism, but I need to collect all of them before going any further (otherwise the next process does not make any sense).

Code works as expected, but I'm struggling with unit tests:

```
@Test
public void extractStuff() {
    // GIVEN
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    List<Token> tokens = buildTokens();
    ...
    // WHEN
    List<Stuff> result = this.instance.extractStuff(scheduler, tokens);
    // Execution never comes to this point...
    // THEN
    ...
}
```

Using debugger, I can see that `Observable.just(...)` looks good (my list of observables is not empty, and I can see my custom mocked object inside).

**Problem:** the execution seems to be stuck at the `Observable.merge(observables).toBlocking()` expression. The line `result.addAll` is never called.

I have tried several things with the `TestScheduler` object, but I cannot manage to make it work. Most examples I've find across the Internet are dealing with a function that returns `Observable` object, so the associated unit test can run `scheduler.advanceTimeBy(...);`. In my situation, I can't apply this approach as `Observable` object are not returned directly.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the code, as posted, is behaving the way you expect. Your `getStuffByToken(...)` method is actually being invoked on the calling thread, not by the `Scheduler`.

For simplicity, let me replace `Token` with `Integer` and `Stuff` with `String`.

My `getStuffByToken(...)` is going to return the `String` representation of `Integer` and will also include the current `Thread`'s name:

```
private List<String> getStuffByToken( Integer token )
{
    return Arrays.asList( token.toString(), Thread.currentThread().getName() );
}
```

I might be on a different version of RxJava, I don't have a `toBlocking(...)` method but have `blockingIterable()` - I hope this is equivalent:

```
public List<String> extractStuff(Scheduler scheduler, List<Integer> tokens) {
    List<Observable<List<String>>> observables = tokens
            .stream()
            .map(token-> Observable.just(getStuffByToken(token)).subscribeOn(scheduler))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<String> stuff: Observable.merge(observables).blockingIterable()) {
        result.addAll(stuff);
    }

    return result;
}
```

If we test the above:

```
@Test
public void testExtractStuff()
{
    List<Integer> tokens = Arrays.asList( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
    List<String> result = extractStuff( Schedulers.computation(), tokens );
    System.out.println( result );
}
```

We get back:

```
[1, main, 3, main, 4, main, 5, main, 2, main]
```

As you can tell all the `getStuffByToken(...)` calls were executed on the `main Thread`.

Next, the reason your test method isn't getting invoked is because `TestScheduler` requires the invocation of the `TestScheduler.advanceTimeBy(...)` to simulate the passing of time that results in processing of your Rx pipeline. Since your method is a blocking method, it's not going to be convenient to test with `TestScheduler`.

Armed with both of the pieces of info above, I'm suggesting you do something along these lines:

```
public Single<List<String>> extractStuff( Scheduler scheduler, List<Integer> tokens )
{
    return Observable.fromIterable( tokens )
        .flatMap( token -> Observable.just( token )
                .subscribeOn( scheduler )
                .map( this::getStuffByToken )
                .flatMap( Observable::fromIterable ))
        .toList();
}
```

You production code can call `extractStuff(...).blockingGet()` to resolve the `List`.

And, you can test as follows:

```
@Test
public void testExtractStuff()
{
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    List<Integer> tokens = Arrays.asList( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
    TestObserver<List<String>> test = extractStuff( scheduler, tokens ).test();

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy( 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
    test.assertValueCount( 1 );
    test.assertValue( list -> list.size() == 10 );
    test.assertComplete();
}
```

Comment: I agree with you that using `TestScheduler` with `advanceTimeBy` is a better solution, yet I have to deal with some legacy code right now. The first solution (with `Schedulers.computation()`) did the trick.

Is there any official documentation where I can find these kinds of information?

Comment: @DavidL, The official documentation is split between a couple of sites.
For generic reactive stream concepts: http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html.
For Java-specific: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava
Unit testing is covered in the "Intro to Rx" book for .NET: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html#TestingRx